# ForEach record insert in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three sql tables `tblDocumentType (Doctypeid)`, `tblDiscipline (DisciplineID)` `tblDocType_Discipline`

For each `Doctypeid` in `tblDocumentType` I need to **insert** all `DisciplineID` and Doctypeid in to `tblDocType_Discipline` table.

What's the best way to write a sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into tblDocType_Discipline
(DocTypeId,DisiplineId)
SELECT  dt.DocTypeID, d.DisciplineId
FROM dbo.tblDocumentType dt
FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.tblDiscipline d 
ON 1 = 1
```

I think you are looking for a full outer join.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a relationship between `Doctypeid` and `DisciplineID` to get the results you want.

Something like this, provided the aforementioned:

```
insert into tblDocType_Discipline
select Doctypeid
from tblDocumentType
where DisciplineID in
(
    select DisciplineID
    from tblDisicpline
)
```

That query assumes that your `tblDocumentType` table has a field for `DisciplineID`.  If it doesn't, there is no way to create that relationship unless you have a separate join table.

Comment: @chamara I have edited my answer, but there are some assumptions I made.  Your given information isn't enough to create this relationship.